# How can I provide a relative path for H2 database file, using hibernate under Tomcat?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, path, h2, relative-path

I have a setup which must be fairly common: I have an H2 db, with a db file. I'm using the db in standalone mode. Hibernate provides access to db and I've deployed my code into Tomcat.

The problem is: I could not find a nice way of simply putting the db file into the `war` and providing a relative path in hibernate config file.

At the moment, I have to use a path to `c://whatever_db_file_container_dir/dbname` in hibernate config.

This stops me from deploying a zero config web app. Is there a way of turning this setup into a self containing zero configuration package?

Comment: At the moment, yes, but it would help a lot if I could use it read-write in the future.

Comment: Well, I thought it would be possible to look for a database on the classpath but I actually don't know if [H2 can do that](http://www.mail-archive.com/h2-database@googlegroups.com/msg00739.html). And this wouldn't fit your future needs anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, H2 doesn't support databases in the classpath (there is a feature request for it, but it's not yet implemented). But this would only work for read-only databases. Unfortunately, H2 also doesn't support system properties in the database URL yet.

However, Hibernate supports [Programmatic configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic). I am not sure how to get the directory of the web application in Tomcat, but I know about [catalina.home and catalina.base](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1121565). So when starting your application, get value of the `catalina.home` system property, and set the Hibernate system property with the database URL accordingly. I didn't try myself, but this is how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to wait for the feature implemented you can set H2 (or HSQL, derby) url dynamically in your code. Check http://www.jvmhost.com/spring-hosting for code example.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.